# Meaning of error message for gdal_translate() and gdalbuildtvrt()?

Tags: gdal, r, gdal-translate, gdalbuildvrt, gdalutils

I am working with `gdal_translate()` and `gdal_buildvrt()` from the `gdalUtils` package in R to merge several batches of a large number of raster files.

This is my code

```
gdalbuildvrt(gdalfile = l, # uses all tiffs in the current folder
               output.vrt = path_vrt,
               overwrite = TRUE)

gdal_translate(src_dataset = path_vrt, 
                 dst_dataset = path, 
                 output_Raster = TRUE,
                 options = c("BIGTIFF=YES", "COMPRESSION=LZW"))
```

where `l` is a list of raster file paths.

In most cases this works completely fine but sometimes in fails (both for `gdalbuildvrt()` and for giving the list directly into `gdal_translate()`) and gives me the message:

```
Error in system(cmd, intern = TRUE) : error in running command
```

which is very general and thus quite cryptic in this context. I unfortunately cannot share my data as they are very large, but as they are processed all the same there should not be an issue. The only thing I noticed is that the batches that failed had the largest number of tiles in them.

So my questions would be

1. What could this error message be telling me inside gdalUtils?
2. Is there a way to retrieve a more detailed error message to learn what is going on in gdal under the hood?
3. Is there a size/file limits for these functions, could this be a reason it fails?

I know that a first step would be to run it directly in gdal but I am working on a server where I do not have direct acess to gdal.

Comment: In Python there is `gdal.UseExceptions()` which tends to give better clarification errors- is there an equivalent in `R` that could help?

Comment: If you can use `gdal_translate()` for some things then you can use `system()` for some things, and if you can use `system()` for some things you can probably get a shell and use gdal command line tools directly, despite it being a server. That doesn't help if its a command line length limit though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a clue: "the batches that failed had the largest number of tiles"

The `system` function which `gdalUtils` functions use will be subject to the operating system limitations on command line lengths.

For example, if I do `system("ls /etc/passwd")` its passing a command of length 20 characters. This works fine. If I do `system("ls /etc/passwd /etc/passwd /etc/passwd ... ")` with 10922 `/etc/passwd`s it works, but 10923 fails. I get a warning that the argument is too long and the same "error in running command" message as you:

```
> system(paste0("ls ",paste(rep("/etc/passwd",10923), collapse=" ")))
Warning messages:
1: In system(paste0("ls ", paste(rep("/etc/passwd", 10923), collapse = " "))) :
  system call failed: Argument list too long
2: In system(paste0("ls ", paste(rep("/etc/passwd", 10923), collapse = " "))) :
  error in running command
```

How many characters is this?

```
> nchar(paste0("ls ",paste(rep("/etc/passwd",10923), collapse=" ")))
[1] 131078
```

which is very close to the nice binary number of 2^17 = 131072, so I reckon that's the limit on my system.  Your operating system may be different.

How many raster files are you putting into your calls? How long are the paths? How long do you think the resulting gdal command line will be? You can do `debug(gdal_translate)` and step through to see the construction of the command line and how long it is before it gets executed at the `system` call. You could also run with `verbose=TRUE` to see the string before execution (and error).

Comment: Hello @Spacedman, thank you for your explanations, which helped me to understand better how gdalUtils operates. Indeed, when I split the failed batches into smaller ones (a quite obvious thing to do in hindsight), they run through fine, so I guess your hypothesis was correct!